# Using react-transition-group with next js navbar

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am currently trying to make my mobile navbar animate on opening, so it doesn't just pop open, make it kind of smooth.

It currently throws this error

```
Server Error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports
```

Here's my code it's effecting

```
<nav className='lg:block lg:static absolute top-0 left-0 fade pb-2 w-full'>
                <button aria-label='Open Navigational Menu on Mobile' className='pt-2.5 pl-2.5 mt-0 m-3 rounded lg:hidden text-black ml-auto hover:text-gray-500 outline-none' onClick={handleClick}>
                     </button>
                <CSSTransitionGroup
                in={active} timeout={300}>
                    <div
                    className={`${
                        active ? '' : 'hidden'
                    }   w-full lg:flex lg:flex-grow lg:w-auto transition-all`}
                    >
                    <div className='bg-white bg-opacity-95 lg:flex divide-y divide-slate-200 lg:flex-row lg:w-screen lg:bg-white lg:text-2xl lg:font-semibold lg:font-poppins lg:justify-center lg:align-middle lg:gap-12 w-full items-start flex flex-col'>
                        <Link href='/'>
                           {currentPage === "/" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Home</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Home</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/aboutme'>
                           {currentPage === "/aboutme" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>About Me</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>About Me</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/portfolio'>
                           {currentPage === "/portfolio" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Portfolio</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Portfolio</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/links'>
                           {currentPage === "/links" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Favorite Links</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Favorite Links</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/blog'>
                           {currentPage === "/blog" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Blog</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Blog</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
                        <Link href='/contact'>
                           {currentPage === "/contact" ? (
                              <a className='text-navPurple font-bold lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Contact Me</a>
                          ) : (
                              <a className='lg:hover:drop-shadow-md lg:w-auto w-full lg:p-0 px-3 py-3 text-navGreen hover:font-semibold lg:border-none' onClick={()=>setActive(false)}>Contact Me</a>
                          )}
                        </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
                </CSSTransitionGroup>
        <div
            className={`${
            active ? '' : 'hidden'
        }   fixed -z-10 inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-70 overflow-y-auto h-full w-full`}
            id="my-modal"
            onClick={()=>setActive(false)}
        ></div>
    </nav>
```

I've tried messing with all the different properties of the CSSTransitionGroup and nothing seems to make this error go away. Do i have it in the wrong spot? Is this library just not compatible? I didn't see anything within Tailwind that looked like it would be capable of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by ditching React-Transition-Group and instead opting to use HeadlessUI, which is made to be compatible with TailwindCSS